# Converting stored int to long in Shared Prefrences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have an app in production that stores lots of data in sharedprefrences.

some of the data is stored as int that is its implemented using sp.setInt...

I have a problem that some of the numbers stored as int are to large and being leaked to negetive numbers.

How can i safely make a convertion to existing users that will make data stored as int, to hold long ? that is instead of setInt i want setLong and getLong.

**I have to make sure that when i do getLong on the currently stored int it will not crash.**

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `SharedPreferences#getLong` to get shared preference previously stored as `int`.

```
int i = 2;
Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
editor.putInt("myint", i);
editor.apply();
long l = sharedPrefs.getLong("myint", 1L);
```

Above code throws `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long`. So use should use new separate shared preference to store your value as `long`.
If you want to move data from `int` shared preference to `long` shared preference for existing users do what Ganapathy points out. Check whether `int` shared preference exists and if it exists read old `int` value with `SharedPreferences#getInt` and store it in new `long` shared preference using `SharedPreferences#putLong`. Then probably you also should remove old `int` shared preference.

```
if(sharedPrefs.contains("myint")) {
    Editor edit = sharedPrefs.edit();
    edit.putLong("mylong" , (long) sharedPrefs.getInt("myInt", 0));
    edit.apply();
    edit.remove("myint");
    edit.apply();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27418391/755804) by @michal.z, you can catch the ClassCastException and retry to get Integer.

So you get:

```
long l=0;
try {
    l = sharedPrefs.getLong("myint", 1L);
} catch (ClassCastException) {
    l = sharedPrefs.getInt("myint", 1L);
    if (l<0) {
        l += 0x80000000L;
    }
}
```

One more good news: once you save "myint" as a Long, the exception will not happen anymore.

Answer (score 0):

you should use separate variable to store long.

If you want to copy data from for existing user,

you can implement a check like the following,

```
spEditor.putLong("myLong" , (long) sp.getInt("myInt", 0));
```

and save it. Above is a sample code. Not a complete code.

Answer (score 0):

Once you set a type to a shared preference field, it is nearly impossible to change it. Your best call is to create a new field and then provide a wrapper method inside the app, which will redirect all calls to the previous (int) field to the new (long) one.